# Create caption using title in <th> tag inside <tfoot> with the value of a query

Tags: php, html

I created two queries that return the total discount amount and the total amount of a book collection.

- `Two querys in PHP code.`

```
    <?php
         require_once "../model/BookDAO.php";

         $sql_total_discount = "SELECT SUM(discount) FROM book";
         $sql_total_value = "SELECT SUM(value) FROM book";
    
         $select_discount = BD::getInstance()->prepare($sql_total_discount);
         $select_value =  BD::getInstance()->prepare($sql_total_value);
    
         $select_discount->execute();
         $select_value->execute();
    
         $line_discount = $select_discount->fetchColumn();
         $line_value = $select_value->fetchColumn();
    ?>
```

The problem is that where you have the `<th title="">` I don't know how to insert the variables `$line_discount` and `$line_value` so that it is possible to create a caption with the value of the two query's in the snippet in PHP.

- `Except <tfoot>`

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th title="">
            <?php
                print_r("R$$line_discount");
            ?>
        </th>
        <th title="">
            <?php
                print_r("R$$line_value");
            ?>
        </th>               
   </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Comment: When the user hovers over the value, create the caption on the value using ```title=""```.

Comment: Are you simply asking how to output those values as the content of the `title` attribute, or what ...? Well by making the output _inside_ of the quotes that delimit this attribute's value - `<th title="<?php ... ?>">`

Comment: @CBroe I understand now that you talked.